# How to tell googlespeech recognition to use a specific phraseset node.js

Tags: node.js, google-speech-to-text-api

We have an evolving Node.js app where we had experimented with:

```
  config: {
    encoding: "MULAW",
    sampleRateHertz: 8000,
    languageCode: "en-US",
    useEnhanced: true,
    model: 'phone_call',
    "speechContexts": [{
      "phrases": [
        { "value": "battalion", "boost": 10 },
        { "value": "italian", "boost": -10 },
      ]
    }
    ]
  },
  singleUtterance: false,
  interimResults: true
};
```

And after some iterative prototypes we also learned how to load phraseset into the google cloud .. so for example our phraseset  that can be set and inspected is similar to:

```
        .createPhraseSet({
            phraseSet: {
                name: "second",
                phrases: newPhrases
            },
            phraseSetId: "PUSDA01",
            parent: "projects/project-id/locations/global",
        })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log("speech api res +++", res);
            console.log("speech api res 218 +++", JSON.stringify(res));
        });
```

So instead of "speechContexts" being an array pushed on every recognition request we want to our config to tell google to use phraset id  "PUSDA01" ... please advise on syntax.

I do not readily see how in: https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-grpc/0.62.0/com/google/cloud/speech/v1p1beta1/SpeechContext.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `phraseset` is already created and you know its name, `phraseset` could be defined in the config. See code below on how to define it in the config. See [RecognitionConfig](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionConfig) for the reference.

NOTE: Though I don't have the actual audio to test, but this syntax should work. Use the updated config for `recognition`. I used your created `phraseset` with **phraseid PUSDA01** as the example:

```
  const phraseSets = {
    phraseSets: [
        {
            name: "projects/your-project-number/locations/global/phraseSets/PUSDA01"
        }
    ]
  };

  config: {
    encoding: "MULAW",
    sampleRateHertz: 8000,
    languageCode: "en-US",
    useEnhanced: true,
    model: 'phone_call',
    adaptation: phraseSets
  },
  singleUtterance: false,
  interimResults: true
};
```

If ever you have multiple `phraseSets` or don't know the `name` of your `phraseSets`, you can use [listPhraseSet()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/speech/latest/google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.Adaptation.html#listPhraseSet2) to get all your available phrases.

Comment: Thank you! We will try this out.  If i had a "common" phrase set plus a specific user "role" phrase set - it looks like the phraseSets is an array so hopeful that can work to suit my needs.